# Password not working when inserting users in Sonarqube in Python

Tags: python, sonarqube

```
user_password = 'admin'
salt = bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=16)
    password = bcrypt.hashpw(user_password.encode('utf-8'), salt)
    print(password)
    sql_statementInsert = "INSERT into users 
(crypted_password,login,uuid,external_login,external_identity_provider,external_id,is_root,onboarded,hash_method,active,name) 
values ('{}','cosmin','1ea2ad82-b07c-11ea-b3de-0242ac130004','cosmin','sonarqube','user',false,true,'BCRYPT',true,'cosmin') on conflict (login) do nothing;".format(password.decode("utf-8"))
```

The generated hash for this example is: $2b$08$1KDDzD5DoVOEopOWUb0Rbu8A0FtYtI02BopFoY4Qxp5URuf3KA0s2.
I have this code which is generating some hash based on the user_password, but when trying to log in with  "admin" value is not working. But when I am inserting directly the following hash in the crypted_password is working: $2a$12$uCkkXmhW5ThVK8mpBvnXOOJRLd64LJeHTeCkSuB3lfaR2N0AYBaSi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using the good library, I needed py-bcrypt, the wrong one was bcrypt only. Also if you use the new lib you don't need to decode the password when you insert it.